# EAGetMail, How to read all emails from POP3 Gmail server?

Tags: c#, email, gmail, pop3

I'm using [EAGetMail](http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=18) library to read emails from Gmail.
This is my code:

```
    private void readMails(){
        MailServer oServer=new MailServer("pop.gmail.com", "something@gmail.com", "noneedtoseethis", ServerProtocol.Pop3);
        MailClient oClient = new MailClient("Client");
        oServer.SSLConnection = true;
        oServer.Port = 995;
        try {
            oClient.Connect(oServer);
            MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
            Console.WriteLine(infos.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++){
                MailInfo info = infos[i];
                Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                //oClient.Delete(info);
            }
            oClient.Quit();
        } catch (Exception ep) {
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        }
    }
```

Though it appears the only thing that it gets are the new messages I receive
 which are 2 or 3 every five minutes.
But I want to read all emails I have in the inbox, not just the new coming messages
How can I do that?

Comment: How do I check if email in spam or trash, ot or inbox folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Gmail POP3 server doesn't work like normal POP3 server, it hides old emails automatically even the email was not deleted, so I suggest that you use IMAP4 protocol, then you will read all emails.

just change:
 server address to imap.gmail.com,
 server port to 993,
 ServerProtocol.Pop3 to ServerProtocol.Imap4

just like this:

```
private void readMails(){
        MailServer oServer=new MailServer("imap.gmail.com", "something@gmail.com", "noneedtoseethis", ServerProtocol.Imap4);
        MailClient oClient = new MailClient("Client");
        oServer.SSLConnection = true;
        oServer.Port = 993;
        try {
            oClient.Connect(oServer);
            MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
            Console.WriteLine(infos.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++){
                MailInfo info = infos[i];
                Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                //oClient.Delete(info);
            }
            oClient.Quit();
        } catch (Exception ep) {
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quick question, I'm about to have to create a system to monitor a few inboxes, would you recommend the EAGetMail library? or is there a better package?

Comment: @Jenny 1985 Are there other ways to connect to Imap4 with SSL to read messages?  Not yet working for me with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook